# jquery .load() with multiple variables

Tags: javascript, jquery, load

I am using the jquery `.load()` method for a search. I have figured out how to send one variable, but I need to send many.

WITH ONE

```
var field1 = ($('#form1 input[name="field1"]:text').val());
$('#results').load("/search/show.php", {field1: field1});
```

How would I do two variables? THIS WONT WORK

```
var field1 = ($('#form1 input[name="field1"]:text').val());
var field2 = ($('#form1 input[name="field2"]:text').val());
$('#results').load("/search/show.php", {field1: field1}{field2: field2});
```

I'm sure there is an easy way to send multiple variables, I just don't know how!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're looking for:

```
var field1 = ($('#form1 input[name="field1"]:text').val());
var field2 = ($('#form1 input[name="field2"]:text').val());
$('#results').load("/search/show.php", {field1: field1, field2: field2});
```

Check out [object literals on the MDC](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Guide/Core_Language_Features#Object_Literals).

Comment: Thanks for the help and thanks so much for the reference, it will be very helpful in the future!